# dynamically load data to bootstrap accordion nav from database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have made a bootstrap accordion nav that loads data dynamically from database with php

here is the 2 tables that i use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `top_tier` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_tier` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `edited_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

so basically the table top_tier is the main items of the accordion nav bar. an entry in the top_tier table can have multiple children from the table sub_tier and that said entry from the sub_tier table can have children too through the column parent_id, its kinda of a hierarchy. so when i click an item from the accordion that's from the top_tier table, it'll show its children then if i click an item from that said top_tier item, it'll show its children items if it has any and so on...

here is the code for the accordion

```
    <div id="MainMenu">
  <div class="list-group panel">
    <?php
    $top_items =  $obj->getTopTierItems();
    foreach($top_items as $top_item) {
    extract($top_item);
    ?>

    <a href="#<?php echo $id;?>" class="strong list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">
      <?php echo $name;?> 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>

    <div class="output collapse" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
      <?php 
      $sub_items = $obj->getSubTierItems($id); 
      foreach($sub_items as $sub_item) {
        $id2 = $sub_item['id'];
        $name2 = $sub_item['name'];
        $parent_id = $sub_item['parent_id'];
      ?>
        <a href="#<?php echo $id2;?>" class="strong list-group-item" data-parent="#<?php echo $parent_id; ?>">
          <?php echo $name2;?>
        </a>

        <div class="output collapse" id="<?php echo $id2; ?>">

        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php 
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the php that fetch the data from the table top_tier

```
public function getTopTierItems(){

        $SQL = "
            SELECT

            id,
            name

            FROM 
                top_tier
            WHERE
                status = 1  
        ";              
        $results = $this->db_query_listx($SQL);
        return $results;
    }
```

here is the php that fetch the data from the table sub_tier

```
public function getSubTierItems($id){

        $SQL = "
            SELECT

            id,
            name,
            parent_id

            FROM
                sub_tier
            WHERE
                status = 1
            AND
                parent_id='$id'

        ";              
        $results = $this->db_query_listx($SQL);
        return $results;
    }
```

here is the function that controls the data from the database.

```
public function db_query_listx($SQL){
        global $connect;
        if ($resultset = $connect->query($SQL)) {
            if ($resultset->num_rows > 0) {

                $data = array();
                    while( $row = $resultset->fetch_assoc() ) {
                        $data[] = array_change_key_case($row);
                    }
                }else {
                $data = NULL;
            }
        } else {
            $data = die("<CENTER><DIV class='error'>ERROR: " . $connect->error . "<BR> ( $SQL ) <HR>
                             Please report this to <a href='#'>webmaster</a>.</DIV></CENTER>");
        }
        $resultset->close();
        return $data;
    }
```

what i want to happen is when i click a child entry from the table sub_tier, it'll display its children entry if it has any.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about already working code, it may be more suitable for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @scrowler i am asking for a way on how to do the above requirement(the question was after the first code block).

Comment: Hi @Christian, I'm sorry but questions regarding improving working code are considered to be off topic. As I can't see a question above and you've said `the code above are working fine. i just wanted to improve it` I've voted to close it, you will get a better response on CodeReview than you will here for improving working code.

Comment: @scrowler alright i'll remove the above said statement. the above code is working but i really don't know how to do what my question is stating... could i ask the same question on CodeReview and ask here at the same time?

Comment: @christian what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @DevfaR i want the items from the sub_tier tables to ouput its children when that said item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure at all if this will help you as I am a student. I just figured out a problem with my accordion. I am also doing it in bootstrap. I think your wanting to be able to have an accordion within an accordion if Im not mistaken. here is a snippet of code that converts multiple accordions in html into php

```
if ($result)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
               {
                   echo '<div class="col-small-6 col-med-6 col-lg-4 albumContainer">';
                   echo '<img src=' . $row['Album_Art'] . 'alt="">';           
                   echo '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">';
                   echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
                   echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
                   echo '<h2 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' . $row['direction'] . '>' . $row['Title'] . '</a></h2></div>';
                   echo '<div id=' . $row['destination'] . ' class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"> <ol>';


                   if($row['id']==1)
                   {
                        foreach ($result1 as $row1) 
                        {                       
                            echo '<li>' . $row1['Name'] . '</li>';  

                        }; 
                    }

                    if($row['id']==2)
                    {
                        foreach ($result2 as $row2)
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row2['Name'] . '</li>';  

                        };
                    }

                    if($row['id']==3)
                    {
                        foreach ($result3 as $row3)
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row3['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    }

                    if($row['id']==4)
                    {
                        foreach ($result4 as $row4)
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row4['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    }

                    if($row['id']==5)
                    {
                        foreach ($result5 as $row5)
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row5['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    }

                    if($row['id']==6)
                    {
                        foreach ($result6 as $row6)
                        {
                            echo '<li>' . $row6['Name'] . '</li>';
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</ol>';
                    echo '<h3>available at:</h3><a href=' . $row['Location'] . '>iTunes</a>
                    <a href=' . $row['Location2'] . '>Amazon</a>
                    <a href=' . $row['Location3'] . '>United Interests</a></div>';
                    echo '</div></div></div></div>';
                }
                    mysqli_free_result ($result); 
        }
```

The IF statements and foreach statement populates each individual accordion. I think what you would want to do is the same thing but keep nesting the IF and foreach statement to create a cascading effect. then just specify through an href="#yourid" to toggle on and off which accordion you want to display. sorry if this doesn't help.